# C++. Templates and run time user information

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, numerical-integration

I've been trying to learn more about generic programming since it's something I think I don't know enough about. So I'm thinking about how I would implement a template version of one of my programs.
The program I am trying to do this with is a numerical integrator program in which the user selects which integrator to use (i.e. Euler, Runge Kutta, etc) and then integrates whatever function they choose.
My current method of doing this is by having an abstract base class called Integrator, and several derived classes that implement the integration method.
So the code would look something like this (much more going on but this is just to show the methodology). Note that I use Qt for this and I declare an Integrator *integrator; in the MainWindow class.

```
void MainWindow::on_integrateButton_clicked() {
string whichIntegrator = getUserChoice();

integrator = getIntegrator( whichIntegrator, whichFunction, order );
integrator->setUp( data ); // things like initial conditions, time, step size, etc...

runIntegratorInNewThread();
}
```

with getIntegrator essentially using the factory method

```
// x being current data, xdot being the results of evaluating derivatives
typedef void (*pFunction)(const double t, const double x[], double *xdot);

Integrator* getIntegrator( const string &whichIntegrator, pFunction whichFunction, int order  ) {
    if (whichIntegrator == "Euler") {
        return new Euler(whichFunction, order);
    } else if (whichIntegrator == "RungeKutta") {
        return new RungeKutta(whichFunction, order);
    }
}
```

So this method works fine, and the integrator program runs very well. Now I know that template functions are generated at compile time and given that I'm using run time information, how would you implement this using templates? If the question is not clear, what I'm asking is... Given a user choice at run time, that being which integrator to use, how do I call the correct integration function using a template method?

Comment: Don't try to apply templates to random situations. They are extremely useful in certain scenarios, but I don't think this one's one of them. Just keep the dynamic polymorphism using virtual functions if it's working OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose it's that I have seen a few integrator codes, all used templates. The difference with them though was it was more of a 'open the cpp file and edit stuff there to run it', whereas mine is a GUI that has all sorts of bells and whistles. I was just interested to see if this could be templated. My current template use extends as far as writing algorithms for containers and I'm sure I could be using them for more than that. Integration is after all, an algorithm of sorts, so perhaps I could have templated it. Seems better to stick with virtual functions here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are not a silver bullet, while you can do a lot with them, don't discount the power of polymorphism which you are currently using.

Can this be done with templates? The answer is Yes and it looks like this using C++11 and shared_ptr:

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> getIntegrator(pFunction whichFunction, int order)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(whichFunction, order);
}
```

And in your caller:

```
std::shared_ptr<Integrator> integrator;
if (whichIntegrator  == "Euler")
{
    integrator = getIntegrator<Euler>(whichFunction, order);
}
else if(whichIntegrator  == "RungeKutta")
{
    integrator = getIntegrator<RungeKutta>(whichFunction, order);
}
```

One other note, is you should be very careful about Memory Leaks here, you are newing up and object and if you're never releasing it, you will have a leak.

**All that being said, I hope this answer shows that while you can use templates, I wouldn't recommend it in this case, Polymorphism works well here.
This example just shows templates in action, in an extremely simple and redundant case**

Comment: How could this work? `which` is supposed to indicate which Integrator to allocate. So what would `T`, which you have to indicate explicitly, be?

Comment: Also, I agree that Templates shouldn't be used here, but he asked if they could and I showed an example.

Comment: Then the answer should be "don't use templates here".

Comment: `getIntegrator` is exactly the same as `make_shared`.

Comment: I decided to up vote this answer as it made the most sense to me as was sort of what I was thinking as well.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I wanted to write this entire system with staticly typed integrators.

I would take your `on_integrateButton_clicked`, and change it to something like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_integrateButton_clicked() {
  string whichIntegrator = getUserChoice();

  runInNewThread( [whichIntegrator,whichFunction,order]() {
    struct functor {
      FunctionType func;
      OrderType order;
      functor( FunctionType func_in, OrderType order_in):func(std::move(func_in)), order(std::move(order_in)) {}
      template<typename Integrator>
      void operator()( Integrator* integrator ) {
        // code using integrator here, not a virtual interface to it, an actual instance of the final type
      }
    };
    RunWithChosenIntegrator( whichIntegrator, functor(whichFunction,order) );
  } );
}
```

As you can see, the code seems a bit backwards.

We defer the type selection as long as possible, and at that point we have it call a `functor` with a pointer to the integrator.  This means that the code that uses the integrator has full type information of the integrator, and isn't dealing with it abstractly.

Usually, runtime polymorphism or type erasure is sufficient for these kinds of problems, however.

Now, `RunWithChosenIntegrator` is a bit of a strange beast.  It would have a signature lookling like this:

```
template<typename Functor>
void RunWithChosenIntegrator( std::string const&whichIntegrator, Functor&& func ) {
  if (whichIntegrator == "bob") {
    BobIntegrator bob;
    func( &bob );
  } else if (whichIntegrator == "alice" ) {
    AliceIntegrator alice;
    func( &alice ):
  }
}
```

as you can see, we call `func` with a different type of object based on the `whichIntegrator` parameter.  There are fun ways you can even generate the `if`/`else if` chains using metaprogramming, but that probably isn't worth learning until you are more comphy with basic template programming.

The `Functor` `func` needs to be able to accept pointers to any and all of the types we call it with.  A simple example might be a `func` that just takes a pointer to a base class, and the one I gave above takes a `T*` template type.

All of this is only worth doing if either the overhead of runtime polymorphism is too high, or if you actually need to interact with the different integrator classes in non-uniform ways that is difficult or impossible to capture via runtime polymorphism.

I doubt that this is the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, plenty to look through here, especially the use of rvalue reference of which I haven't actually used yet.